# How can I add procedural porcelain cracks?

Tags: texturing

Okay,I'm gonna ask this and I hope to God this isn't a duplicate of another question. Do you remember in FNaF Sister Location how the plastic suits of the animatronics like Circus Baby have that porcelain crack texture to it? Well,I'm trying to replicate it for my plastic material in Cycles,but when I try procedurally,I fail. I resorted to textures online and I still failed. Can you please help me out?

[image]

Comment: There is currently no good way to make that pattern procedurally. UV map and texture your object. Creating an image texture is the only practical way.

Comment: I think the [cracks tutorial](http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/cracks/) is mostly what you want, and the [leather material](http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/blender-tutorial-chair-materials/) might get you closer to the pattern you are looking for.

Comment: This might help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSB-v4upJzI
Ady explains how to create procedural cracks and store them in a nodegroup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest that I could find procedurally is something like the following, but the brick pattern really is **Too** consistent, that's why I tried to break up the mix with the musgrave texture, and the Random values for the monotony of the brick pattern (see below for the node arrangement).

[image]

Here's the Result on a sphere - keep in mind, it's not all that impressive, but should serve as a good basis to build from should you pursue it further.

[image]

---

I have another attempt here, and thought if we could some how mix the structures, we would have a pretty good method. So here it goes:

[image: Musgrave Node Setup]

[image: Rendered Result on Suzanne]

Comment: Thanks Rick.

You gave me a good suggestion,and so I reward you for your valiant efforts.